# Can Windows Web Server 2008 be used to host games?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

I'm currently using a linux server, we run a couple of web sites of it, PHP apps with MySQL, the usual. Since the server is privately owned by some friends and myself (we do have it hosted at a professional datacenter though), from time to time we also use it to host our smallish counter-strike source and call of duty 4 matches by running the released dedicated game server packages.

I've recently subscribed to DevExpress' excellent WinForms and ASP.Net component suite, and is contemplating moving to Windows to make use of those ASP.Net components. I'm currently trying to decide between the Web and Standard editions of Windows Server, since there is a difference of nearly a thousand bucks (where I come from)

For Windows Web Server 2008, Microsoft has softened the database server restrictions and made it clear there is no need for CALs. But would one be able to run the above mentioned web servers? I've been googling and searching through forums to no avail.

Need some help before I plunk in the cash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I give any opinion, I'll start by answering your core questions:

- Yes, you can run dedicated game servers on Windows Server Web ed.
- The differences between web and standard:

  - Web only supports 2 gigs of ram. Standard in 64bit mode can support 32gigs (and more?).
  - Standard comes with more things that are better suited to local server environments (eg: active directory). If you want LDAP controlled Exchange email, you'll need Standard. Most web server don't need these.
  - Web (apparently) won't support full-on SQL server versions. Express should run though.

Opinion time.

Dedicated and virtual dedicated monetary overheads on Windows servers are a lot... To the degree where you're paying more for the software than the hardware costs, at least for the first year.

Renting the software (as part of a managed dedicated server or VPS) is initially a lot cheaper, but over the course of a couple of years, will cost you about the same and if you run it longer, it'll eventually cost you more.

Shared Windows hosts can be good. I've been with a company called [Hostek](http://www.hostek.com) (Florida-based) and they've bent over backwards to make hosting a fairly busy site (around 6000 uniques a day) very cheap for me. It can also be atrocious. I've had bad hosting companies too. Shop around.

About a year ago, I dropped Windows at home in favour of Linux. I'm not going to enumerate the many benefits and drawbacks; I'll just tell you that that's when I stopped doing .NET in favour of more open Frameworks. I'm not using Django (a Python-based web framework). While you might not like it (or other frameworks - eg Ruby on Rails), **I plead that you do check out what's happening in the open-source world before you plonk for anything Windows related** since you already have the infrastructure available for hosting Django/Rails/et al.

If you wanted your *own* Linux server, VPSs start from around $20pcm. As I said before, severely cheaper than Windows counterparts.  I now use [Linode](http://linode.com) to host everything new I make. Highly affordable and they'll easily run dedicated games like your current set-up does.

Mono isn't an option for you. Not yet anyway. It does go some length to help people migrate their applications but it's still pretty sketchy on the ASPNET front. And as a comment says on another answer: the controls you want to use are strictly Windows-only for the moment.

Linux will consume fewer baseline resources than Windows will. On an old server (Windows 2000, IIRC) I had to administer, the core of Windows would consume anywhere from 100-200 megs of RAM. My current Ubuntu server eats 40megs. I'm not sure how much RAM you have to play with on your server but if it's a lower amount, you're going to fit a lot more on a Linux host. (Remember that if you have more than 2gigs, you don't have the choice of the Web Server edition)

It's clear from this that I'm a complete Linux super-enthusiast, but I know my needs differ from yours. **ASP.NET is a *great* platform** but it costs a lot of money even if you're splitting it between friends. You could opt for Windows... Or you could go Linux, donate a bit to the projects you use and buy a new plasma or something shiny for the lady.

Comment: My server's already colocated, so I'd like to keep using it. I'm currently on 2GB so Web's limit is fine for me now, though I can see it can be a prob in future.

I'm have been running my sites on PHP & CodeIgnitor, but would like to be able to use my .NET components, as they're already paid for. =)

Comment: They have a 30-day refund option =)

Comment: Scrub that, perhaps it's 60 days.

Comment: Either way, just make sure you've evaluated the whole scene before throwing another bucket of money away. Django is at least 30 times better than any PHP framework I've worked with (in terms of code volume, time to create and ease to maintain).

Comment: Trust me, I'd want to save my dough if I can help it =), but among the languages and IDEs I've used, I've been more productive with VB.Net than any other languages thus far.

Thanks for the Django recommendation, but it's in python and I'd rather not have to learn another language at this time.

Answer (score 0):

SPLA? Isn't that for service providers? My friends and I use the hosted services for ourselves (games, email and web), though of course our web sites are publicly viewable by all; but I think that hardly qualifies as "providing a service"?

Unfortunately, staying with Linux would make it such that I would not be able to use my DevExpress components, which is my reason for considering Windows Server in the first place. .NET may be partially supported by Mono, but not fully, and DevExpress makes use of certain features of .NET that aren't (at least as yet) supported by Mono.

We also already own our own dedicated server, so are only looking for a suitable OS.

Still, your reply is appreciated.

Comment: A game isnt something you need SPLA for, but asp.net sure does require you having it WHEN you take the application publicly. Then it's certified as a service.

Comment: So say I write a project management ASP.Net application for my own use, make it accessible from the net so I can access it anywhere, but keep it password protected, I have to pay for SPLA??

Another example: say I'm an ISV and sell software via my coded ecommerce webapp. I have to pay SPLA as well?

Comment: The first example: No you don't need it. However as soon as the application is "authenticated" which means others, in a comersial way, get's access to the application, or /  and if anyone else than you can remote desktop, you need SPLA. It's silly. But read the EUAL for Windows and you'll see :)

Comment: No wonder people say Microsoft is evil *grin*. 

Well, I don't intend to let anyone access the internals of my webapp and definitely not remote desktop to our server. The apps are internal use only.